# Кнопка в проекте android kotlin работает неправильно

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Создал кнопку, функцию. При открытии проекта на android`е - кнопка на первое нажатие не откликается, а на второе - выполняет функцию два раза подряд. Что делать? Такое происходит вне зависимости от функции, которая должна быть выполнена. Иногда бывает так, что работает с первого раза, но делает onClick 2 раза.
Вот код кнопки в XMLе:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="206dp"
        android:layout_height="907dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:background="@color/teal_200"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:onClick="secondact"
        tools:ignore="TextContrastCheck,TextContrastCheck" />
```

Comment: Может просто эмулятор/UI тормозит?

Comment: Много лет подряд вижу проблемы с таким назначение слушателя нажатий. Проще сделать программное назначение. Типа так: `findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener { /*тут код вызовется по клику на кнопку*/ }`